# React styles prop returns [object object] for an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles

I've got this very basic component:

```
Tile = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var styles = [
            TileStyles.tile
        ];
        return (
            <div style={styles} test="test" />
        );
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it is producing this html:

```
<div style="0:[object Object];" data-reactid=".0.$0"></div>
```

Why does it give me [object object] instead of the inline styles?
Obviously I don't need to use an array here but I do on a more complex component.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the answers guys but the issue is I WANT to be able to use multiple styles.

aka use TileStyles.tile and TileStyles.active under certain circumstances.

Comment: check your browser console - it should be generating an error along the lines of "you must pass a style object". You can't pass an array into the JSX style attribute.

Comment: gotcha... I can do this on react-native so I assumed I could here as well. Oh will thanks for the help guys

Comment: worth not doing using react-native, too =)

Comment: I ran in to this issue because I got linked to this article: https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/blob/master/04%20-%20Layout/04%20-%20Inline%20Styles.md without noticing it was about react-future. Glad you brought it up here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is (as already stated) that you give the style property an array, but an object is expected.
So simply changing the code to this:

```
Tile = React.createClass({
    render: function(){

        var style = _.extend({},TileStyles.tile,TileStyles.active);

        return (
            <div style={style} test="test" />
        );
     }
});
```

Here `_` is a dependency on either lodash or underscore. This will work if you defined TileStyles as something like:

```
var TileStyles = {
    tile: { width: '200px', height: '200px', backgroundColor: 'blue' },
    active: { backgroundColor: 'green' }
}
```

If you don't want a dependency on `_`, it is possible to do it by hand, but it can be a hassle.

**Update 2016-03-29:**
Instead of relying on a dependency like `lodash` or `underscore` or doing it by hand, you can use the new [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) feature in ecmascript 2015.

```
var style = Object.assign({},TileStyles.tile,TileStyles.active);
```

Or take the example fully updated to ecmascript 2015:

```
class Tile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const style = Object.assign({},TileStyles.tile,TileStyles.active);
        return <div style={style} test="test" />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I WANT to be able to use multiple styles. aka use TileStyles.tile + TileStyles.active.

Comment: Like controlling it by a state variable? If so, I've have a minor change to the answer.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it know. You want to stack styles like in css, right?

Comment: Yep exactly! I actually came to the same solution you updated to an hour back! Thanks for the validation <3

Comment: No problem, glad we found the right solution :) If you want, you can improve this to use prebuilt styles with same power, by using extend to prebuild the TileStyles object.

Answer (score 3):

React is expecting an object to be passed as styles argument, not an array, so you will need to change it to

```
Tile = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div style={TileStyles} test="test" />
        );
    }
});
```

You will have to make sure that TileStyles returns an (or is an) object and is accesible within the scope, otherwise, create a function in the class scope and call it with

```
this.TileStyles()
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I WANT to be able to use multiple styles. aka use TileStyles.tile + TileStyles.active.